Diagonal line from start to endpoints in log x-scale matplotlib
I am trying to plot a diagonal line from point (0, 0) to (1, 1) in matplotlib using a logarithmic x-scale. This is the MWE:
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()

I would expect to see an exponential function in such a log-normal plane, something that I get using
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.plot(x, x)

but I see a ~horizontal line at y=1. It is similar for the plt.yscale('log'), but it is expectedly a ~vertical line at x=1 this time. Is this expected behaviour?

There is no 0 in a log scale (log(0) -> -Inf).
You should use a small enough value close to 0:
plt.plot([0.0001, 1], [0.0001, 1])
plt.xscale('log')

Output:

If you want a curve:
x = np.linspace(0.0001, 1, 100)
# or better
x = np.logspace(-4, 0, 100)

plt.plot(x, x)
plt.xscale('log')

Output:

Note that using initially a linear scale, then changing to log should also give a valid output:
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.plot(x, x)
plt.xscale('log')

Output:

